# Possible Boolean Tests

Tags: c#, boolean

I am trying to create a for loops in C# to do all possible tests of 3 bool variables, but I can't figure out how to do it the something along the lines of `( a && b ) || c` if `a` is True and `b` and `c` are False the whole statement would equal false.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Create loops to test all possible outcomes, e.g. change a to = False

Comment: ??? 
Specify what you want to do. Do a truth table, something like:
a | b | c | result
t | t | t | t
and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to run unit tests?

Comment: What? the "outcomes" will depend on the specific operation you perform on these bools. for example if you && them all together it will be different than if you || them.

Comment: There are 256 different functions that map three bools to a single bool. Do you really want to write them all out by hand?

Comment: I do not now what your question is all about. Sry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but with nested `foreach`, you can do this:

```
foreach (var a in new[] { false, true, })
  foreach (var b in new[] { false, true, })
    foreach (var c in new[] { false, true, })
    {
      // use a, b, and c here
    }
```

Or in a style preferred by a comment:

```
bool[] arr = { false, true, };
foreach (var a in arr)
  foreach (var b in arr)
    foreach (var c in arr)
    {
      // use a, b, and c here
    }
```

Comment: Probably want to create the array once and iterate over it lots, rather than creating lots and lots of arrays (11 in this case) that are never mutated that have the same value.

Comment: @Servy I edited. I try to count and get `1+2+4` or `7` array creations in the first version. Inner-most code block runs 8 times. It generalizes to `Pow(m, k) - 1` and `Pow(m, k)` where `m` is the length of the array (here `2`), and `k` is the number of `foreach` statements nested this way. The point set is `{ x1, x2, x3, ..., xm } ^ k` where `^` denotes Cartesian power.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right, it's 7, I double counted the lowest level by accident.  The main point (which you made) is that it will scale *very* quickly as the number of loops and/or items per loop increase, and the resulting code is easier to write, not harder, so there's no good reason not to make the change.

Comment: Hmm, typo. It's `(Pow(m, k) - 1) / (m - 1)` array creations.

Answer (score 1):

This version allows some flexibility to expand upon:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    bool a = (i & 1) != 0;
    bool b = (i & 2) != 0;
    bool c = (i & 4) != 0;

    Console.WriteLine("a={0},b={1},c={2}", a, b, c);
  }
```